# How to create an "Add To Cart" button and update the product to a table corresponds to the header?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a simple project, basically an online fruit stall. I'm facing an issue right now is that my current JS function can't trigger the "Add to cart" button to update the shopping cart table (i.e. when I pressed it, nothing happened).

I really need all of y'all help on this, I tried chatGPT but it doesn't seem to be giving me the right solution. This is my current work. Do note that I'm trying this function on one of the products, hence why I only post the code of the watermelon one

**HTML**

```
 <div class="card">
       <div class="sale-badge" id="saleBadge1">Sale!</div>
       <div class="img"><img src="Images/watermelon.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div class="title">Watermelon</div>
       <div class="price"><span class="strike">$5</span>$2.50</div>
       <div class="btn-container">
          <button class="btn" id="addToCartBtn1" onclick="addToCart('Watermelon', 2.50)">Add to cart</button>
       </div>                
</div>
```

**shopping.js**

```
/* ADD CELL AFTER PRESSING ADD TO CART */
function addToCart(productName, productPrice) {
    console.log(productName + ', ' + productPrice);
    // Get the table body where cart items will be added
    var cartTableBody = document.querySelector('.shopping-cart');
    console.log(cartTableBody)

    // Create a new row for the cart item
    var newRow = cartTableBody.insertRow();
    console.log(newRow)
    
    // Create cells for product name and price
    var productNameCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var productPriceCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
    
    // Set the content of the cells
    productNameCell.textContent = productName;
    productPriceCell.textContent = '$' + productPrice.toFixed(2);
}
```

**Current table created with 1 sample row**

```
 <table class="shopping-cart">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 40px;"></th>
                        <th style="width: 90px;"></th>
                        <th style="width: 500px;">Product</th>
                        <th style="width: 90px;">Price</th>
                        <th style="width: 160px;">Quantity</th>
                        <th style="width: 90px;">Subtotal</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cross-symbol">
                            <div class="circle"  onclick="deleteRow(this)">&times;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="image-cell">
                            <img src="Images/watermelon.jpg">
                        </td>
                        <td>Watermelon</td>
                        <td>$2.50</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="quantity">
                                <button class="minus">-</button><input type="text" class="number" value="1" min="1"><button class="plus">+</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Pictures for reference
[image: press "add to cart"][image: should update table like this. I hardcode it so everyone will know what I want]

As you can see from the above two images, what I want is to press the "add to cart" of watermelon, and the content of the cards will be updated in the shopping cart corresponding to the header of the table.

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. You can always DM me to discuss! Thanks!

Comment: Are you including `shopping.js` in the same HTML file as your `<button onclick="addToCart('Watermelon', 2.5)">`? Did you open your browser's Console tab to see if you have any JS errors? "Nothing happened" isn't the most useful debugging statement (but there are worse, i.e. "didn't work")...

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, shopping.js is already included in html file. I've opened the console log and it just says there's error with "insertRow()"

Comment: When an error is triggered in JS, it stops all subsequent code execution, so the "nothing happened" is triggered by that. What is the error that's being triggered? Did you look it up and try to figure it out? Being able to debug your code by encountering and fixing errors is a critical skill of being a developer.

Comment: @TimLewis I tried to look up the error but to no avail. Thats why I had no choice but to post my problem here. From what ChatGPT says, it is because the js function couldn't find a related table to insert my content into, and told me to check the "id" of my table whether it corresponds to the querySelector. But mine already corresponds..

Comment: ChatGPT is not a reliable source for debugging code (in my experience anyway). Again, what is the actual error? It's fine to post your problem here, but you didn't _really_ post your problem here (i.e. you omitted what is arguably the most important part of your problem, which is the actual error message )

Answer (score 3):

The code starts by selecting all elements with class "card" and setting a "click" event handler for each card.
The cart and total are obtained via document.getElementById.
Created a selectedItems object to track selected items with their quantity and price.
The handleCardClick function handles clicks on cards, adding the selected items to the selectedItems object or increasing their number.
The updateCart, addItem and removeItem functions update the cart contents and total when adding/removing items.
Inside the updateCart function, list elements are created to display the selected products in the cart, as well as “+” and “-” buttons that allow you to change the number of products in the cart. Finally, the forEach loop applies an event handler to each card on the page so that users can add products to their cart, and the cart and total interface automatically updates as they do so.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
        const cart = document.getElementById('cart');
        const totalElement = document.getElementById('total'); 
        const selectedItems = {};

        function handleCardClick(event) {
            const card = event.currentTarget;
            const itemId = card.id;
            const itemName = card.querySelector('h2').textContent;
            const itemPrice = parseFloat(card.querySelector('.price').textContent); 

            if (selectedItems[itemId]) {
                selectedItems[itemId].count++;
            } else {
                selectedItems[itemId] = {
                    name: itemName,
                    price: itemPrice,
                    count: 1,
                };
            }

            updateCart();
        }

        function updateCart() {
            cart.innerHTML = '';
            let total = 0; 

            for (const itemId in selectedItems) {
                const item = selectedItems[itemId];
                const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                const quantityContainer = document.createElement('div'); 
                const quantityText = document.createElement('span'); 
                const addButton = document.createElement('button');
                const subtractButton = document.createElement('button');

                addButton.textContent = '+';
                subtractButton.textContent = '-';

                quantityText.textContent = item.count; 

                addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    addItem(itemId);
                });

                subtractButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    removeItem(itemId);
                });

                const hr = document.createElement('hr');

                quantityContainer.appendChild(subtractButton); 
                quantityContainer.appendChild(quantityText); 
                quantityContainer.appendChild(addButton); 
                quantityContainer.appendChild(hr); 

                listItem.textContent = `${item.name} - $${item.price * item.count}`;
                listItem.appendChild(quantityContainer); 
                cart.appendChild(listItem);

                total += item.price * item.count; 
            }

            totalElement.textContent = `Общая сумма: $${total.toFixed(2)}`; 
        }

        function addItem(itemId) {
            if (selectedItems[itemId]) {
                selectedItems[itemId].count++;
            }
            updateCart();
        }

        function removeItem(itemId) {
            if (selectedItems[itemId]) {
                selectedItems[itemId].count--;
                if (selectedItems[itemId].count <= 0) {
                    delete selectedItems[itemId];
                }
            }
            updateCart();
        }

        cards.forEach((card) => {
            card.addEventListener('click', handleCardClick);
        });
```

```css
 * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }

  .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
      gap: 10px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10px;
      max-width: 1100px;
      min-height: 100vh;
  }

  aside,
  main {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      padding: 10px;
  }

  .cards {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .card {
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <aside>
            <aside>
                <h2>Product Basket</h2>
                <ul id="cart"></ul>
                <div id="total">Total Amount: $0</div>
            </aside>
        </aside>
        <main>
            <div class="cards">
                <div class="card" id="apple1">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstbr" alt="apple">
                    <h2>Apple</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">8</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="apple2">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstby" alt="apple">
                    <h2>Apple</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">9</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="banana1">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstch" alt="banan">
                    <h2>Banan</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">10</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="banana2">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstch" alt="banan">
                    <h2>Banan</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">11</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="banana3">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstch" alt="banan">
                    <h2>Banan</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">12</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="cherry1">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstco" alt="cherry">
                    <h2>Cherry</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">13</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="cherry2">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstco" alt="cherry">
                    <h2>Cherry</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">8</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="cherry3">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstco" alt="cherry">
                    <h2>Cherry</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">8</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="grape1">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstct" alt="grape">
                    <h2>Grape</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">8</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="grape2">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstct" alt="grape">
                    <h2>Grape</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">8</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id="grape3">
                    <img src="http://surl.li/lstct" alt="grape">
                    <h2>Grape</h2>
                    <p><mark><span class="price">8</span>$</mark></p>
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>


        </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing. I've not tried it yet but I'll give it a go tomorrow. Thanks for the guidance. 

I will need some time to edit my code with reference to yours

Comment: I was happy to assist

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to Dovgal's solution. I used `element.insertAdjacentHTML()` and a template string to generate new DOM elements instead of a series of `document.createElement()` and `element.appendChild()` calls and I also re-used the global `prods` object to keep track of the ordered quantities in the cart. Apart from that I used delegated event handling within the `#cart` and `#products` DOM elements to trigger the calling of the `prod2cart(id,inc)` function which adds or removes an item from the cart depending on the value of `inc`.

```js
const prods={apples1:["g858f0ecdc78a9d65b19ba3280e479cfefa8b768210d0ff9046964febfe35ad49fb2595e576af9185e0798c2d9786419438838c0448d9ff8396e8fa1b350acd27c642cd12ab0e3123bfd761fb2a3c0193_640.jpg","Apples ",2.49,0],apples2:["g05f9e5ddfd7f0a3eeda4664f5b4d5bedb1861ef0013e9e450970c1d5135e63527038cad98d4cd10099c2dd5d4f69d042fdb6df2f510f068f043577fb85372dd05bff04779747a0917f5cf739171a949a_640.jpg","Apples ",2.99,0],bananas1:["g6f28668f99cfa55e199a8c21ef32cfe5346492cb21989932e2d05fa551c537843c69bf03dda5a571960e599f1a06db5d357250c9d93f7ff0feefa10142c9bdedc8905c6a8be3a9a7a81f5391b35ea9ff_640.jpg","Bananas ", 3.99,0],cherries1:["ga1c99205c38ec60fd200b7dd6b17d28049127fc0699ae6c39cfa83b832bd381e4cfafcb8c5e7244d2ab8e50e4f7c73a5ae00683e20f511fec00751c5c595ec068d9f6752c90761fb9db88cc616315c23_640.jpg","Cherries ",5.99,0],grapes1:["g24afa0e8be5df9fde87ff3ab30fd71a043cbdc703d36b7f2f882fcc424c8d95563f7742443bb5a7c6a573464ec7e792429b84c0327a083bfbc2a66874ee723bdd6099908b13fa7089260f66a67058a2e_640.jpg","Grapes ", 4.49,0],grapes2:["g525a5e5e126936b736ad241599378386eefeb7984034577265bc4e3a1d88a087b323143f343dd77a4c9455f57d9e00bc80e76db7906fd199635bcf86530f99e01dcaffd29a7b6a7979959d048f4983e6_640.png","Grapes ", 5.99,0]};
const [cart,products,sum]=["cart","products","sum"].map(id=>document.getElementById(id));
products.innerHTML=Object.entries(prods).map(([id,[pic,name,price]])=>`<div data-id="${id}"><h2>${name}</h2><img src="https://pixabay.com/get/${pic}"><br>
price per kg: ${price}$</div>`).join("<hr>");
function prod2cart(id,inc){
  let [pic,name,price,qty]=prods[id],
      n=(prods[id][3]+=inc)
      tr=document.getElementById(id);
  if(tr)
   if(!n) tr.remove();
   else {
    tr.querySelector(".qty").textContent=n;
    tr.querySelector(".subttl").textContent=(n*price).toFixed(2);
   }
  else {
   cart.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`<tr id="${id}"><td><img src="https://pixabay.com/get/${pic}"></td>
   <td>${name}</td>
   <td>${price}</td>
   <td><button data-inc="-1">-</button><span class="qty">${n}</span><button data-inc="1">+</button></div></td>
   <td class="subttl">${(price*n).toFixed(2)}</td>
  </tr>`);
  }
  let total=Object.values(prods).reduce((a,[_,__,pr,n])=>a+pr*n,0);
  sum.textContent=total?`Total: ${total.toFixed(2)}$`:"";
}
cart.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
 if(ev.target.tagName!="BUTTON") return;
 let inc=+ev.target.dataset?.inc;
 if (inc) prod2cart(ev.target.closest("tr").id,inc); 
});
products.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  let id=ev.target.closest("div").dataset?.id;
  if(id) prod2cart(id,1);
})
```

```css
#products img {width:100px}
#cart img {width: 50px}
input {width:12px}
#cart, #products {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping cart</h1>
<table id="cart">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Product</th>
   <th>Price</th>
   <th>Quantity</th>
   <th>Subtotal</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<span id="sum"></span>
<h1>Products</h1>
<div id="products">
</div>
```

This implementation does not recreate the whole shopping cart, whenever a single item is changed. Instead it will only recalculate the changed quantities and display them in their allocated spaces.